# Difference between Array and Dictionary in YAML

Tags: yaml

I understand the difference between an array and dictionary, say in python - especially when it comes to accessing content in both.

But in YAML, I kinda find it difficult to differentiate between the two especially when it comes to writing structures. Please How do they differ in their definitions?

Answer (score 2):

```
# YAML sequences (aka Python lists)

# option 1: block style
departments:
  - marketing
  - sales
  - security

# option 2: flow style

departments: [marketing, sales, security]


# YAML dictionary

marketing:
  team-size: 20
  location: nyc

# expanding the sequence to include dictionaries

departments:
  - marketing:
      team-size: 20
      location: nyc
  - sales:
      team-size: 30
      location: sf
  - security:
      team-size: 10
      location: mia
```

Given your familiarity with Python, I'll focus more on syntax:

- Sequences come in two styles: **block** and **flow**. When using block style, each element in the list is preceded by a dash and space `-`
- Dictionaries come in the form of key: value pairs. They are defined with a name, colon and space `name:`
- For every key: value pairing, the value is stored as a scalar (i.e. single value, not real number)
- These scalars themselves can become keys to other value mappings
- You can have nested sequences (lists) and nested mappings (dictionaries)

To clarify with an example: `option 1` above shows a block style sequence. This is denoted with the spacing + `-`. We can convert each element, or value, in that mapping to a scalar by creating further indentations without the `-` (see `#expanding the sequence`)

Answer (score -1):

@kebanus ...here's an example I am looking at

...everything looks like a normal dictionary to me...but the author calls them an array _ apart from the first basic key-value pairs:

```
doe: "a deer, a female deer"
ray: "a drop of golden sun"
pi: 3.14159
xmas: true
french-hens: 3
calling-birds:
  - huey
  - dewey
  - louie
  - fred
xmas-fifth-day:
  calling-birds: four
  french-hens: 3
  golden-rings: 5
  partridges:
    count: 1
    location: "a pear tree"
  turtle-doves: two
```

Comment: If you want to provide additional details, please edit your question. This is not an answer. Also this is not even valid YAML, `doe` cannot have a scalar and a mapping value at the same time.